# Notification not vibrating and led isn't blinking

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, notifications

Here is my code, which is invoked by the `onMessageReceived` function.

I have already added vibration permission to the manifest file. What am I missing? No vibration when the phone is on normal sound mode and no led blink at all.

```
private fun showNotification(title: String?, body: String?) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
        )
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.applogoo_round)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
             .setColor(Color.argb(1, 92, 221, 198))
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
            CHANNEL_ID, "Foreground Service Channel",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )
        serviceChannel.enableLights(true)
        serviceChannel.lightColor=Color.YELLOW
        serviceChannel.enableVibration(true)
        serviceChannel.shouldVibrate()
        serviceChannel.vibrationPattern

        serviceChannel.lockscreenVisibility


        val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        manager!!.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with custom vibration on getting notification

```
private fun vibrate() {
    val mVibratePattern = longArrayOf(
        0, 400, 800, 600, 800, 800, 800, 1000, 400, 800, 600,
        800, 800, 800, 1000, 400, 800, 800, 600, 800, 800, 800, 1000, 400, 800
    )
    val v = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            v.vibrate(
                VibrationEffect.createWaveform(
                    mVibratePattern,
                    VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE
                )
            )
        } else { //deprecated in API 26
            v.vibrate(1000)
        }

    }, 1000)
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dharmender Manral
it fixed my problem
can you suggest something for led light? my led is not working properly too